# Alterar color icon button javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Tenho o botão:

```
<button id="btnVoltar" style="margin-bottom:0;vertical-align:middle" type="button" class="btn-flat bg-red btn-circle-lg waves-effect" onclick="voltaparaConsulta()">
    <i class="material-icons">arrow_back</i>
</button>
```

Consigo alterar a cor do icon dele com um javascript sem problema usando a sintaxe abaixo:

```
document.getElementById("btnEditar").style.color = "#FFFFFF";
```

Porém queria que isso fosse alterado somente caso o button estivesse disable.
Para deixar disable uso a seguinte sintaxe:

```
document.getElementById("btnEditar").disabled = true;
```

Como faço isso?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usando CSS com a pseudo classe `disabled`. Você define a cor no CSS, e desativa o botão com JavaScript normalmente.

Veja funcionando:

```js
document.getElementById('desativar').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById("btnVoltar").disabled = true;
});
```

```css
button:disabled {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet" />

<button id="btnVoltar">
    <i class="material-icons">arrow_back</i>
</button>

<button id="desativar">Clique para desabilitar o botão</button>
```

Comment: blz, isso mesmo. valeu